# Windows based DAW control surface

Tags: audio, daw

I recently purchased a touched screen-enabled windows based laptop for use on the go. As it supports 10 point multitouch, I thought a great use of it while at my desk would be as a touch screen DAW control surface for my mackie compatible DAW (in my case, Adobe Audition 3), presumable connecting over the network. I am aware that there are control surface apps for Android and iPad ( I actually use TouchDAW for my android tablet), but a google search hasn't shown anything for Windows.

Has anyone here heard of a Windows based DAW control surface program?

Answer (score 1):

Emulator Pro
http://smithsonmartin.com/products/emulator-pro/

With Emulator PRO, the only performance hardware you need is a Windows* device. The software is solid, so you can rely on it for live performances. Get ready to rock the house with minimum setup and maximum impact.

- Windows version is compatible with Windows 7 & 8. OSX version is currently available with Emulator ELITE only.

Answer (score 0):

yMIDI should do what you need, you'll need rtpMIDI as well to do MIDI over the network.

http://www.level6productions.com/ymidi.html